# Is there any way to make mdfind (the spotlight command line) find symlinks?

Tags: terminal, spotlight

I use `mdfind` extensively to look for files on my file system because it is so much faster than `find`.  In this case, I was looking for `README.md` files.

But today I just realized I was missing some files because they were actually symlinks.

Let me give you an example:

```
rm -rf test
mkdir test
cd test
touch foo.md bar.md test.txt test2.txt
ln -s test2.txt zoom.md
cd ..
```

OK, now if `tree` it I see:

```
test
├── bar.md
├── foo.md
├── test.txt
├── test2.txt
└── zoom.md -> test2.txt
```

and using `find test -name "*.md"` :

```
test/bar.md
test/foo.md
test/zoom.md
```

but `mdfind -onlyin test -name md` doesn't match the symlink `zoom.md`:

```
..../test/test/foo.md
..../test/test/bar.md
```

From [this](https://arstechnica.com/civis/threads/using-spotlight-to-find-unix-symlinks-not-os-x-aliases.1109635/), it looks like specifying `"kMDItemContentType == public.symlink"` might help.  It didn't.

Looked around some more for `kMDItemContentType` online, but Apple for some reason provides next to no documentation about `mdfind` advanced usage.

Answer (score 1):

The Spotlight index (as used by `mdfind`) indexes files and folders. But a symlink is not a file.  It is a link to a file.  It is the file which is indexed.

On the the other hand, an alias is a file and is indexed by Spotlight. Its UTI is `com.apple.alias-file`.

Unless you are prepared to change your symlinks to aliases, the answer to the question is: No, you can't find symlinks with `mdfind`.

But you can use `find` to search for symlinks.  For example `find . -type l -ls` finds all symlinks below the current directory.

Comment: In [Unix and Linux, everything is considered a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225537/everything-is-a-file) including symlinks.  It’s just symlinks are a file type that is **not** indexed by Spotlight.

Comment: Yeah, aside from the "not a file" claim, you're probably right.  symlinks seem to be 2nd class citizens to Spotlight.  FWIW `mdls` returns the same metadata for the symlink as for the file.  What I've ended doing is inverting which files are real and which symlinks:  my organization is to track issues as directories under a certain location with a `README.md` file.  Then I came with a way to generate `checklist.md` as a reminder of things I needed to fix.  So `ln -s checklist.md README.md` and I've got both my readme and my checklist, right?  Wrong, mdfind finds no `README.md`.

Comment: So, generate checklist as `README.md` and then `ln -s README.md checklist.md`.  mdfind still finds its files.  Still, an annoyance in `mdfind`.  I am well aware of `find` usage, in fact I used `find . -name README.md -type l` to identify where I had this problem.  The only thing is `mdfind` is awesomely faster... when it works as expected.  I'll leave this out for a while.  If no one else contradicts you and has a better solution then I'll accept it later.  Upvoted.

Comment: @Allan I am very much not an expert on file systems, but my understanding is that at one time unix systems did store symlinks in files, but that this is no longer true. Most POSIX systems implement fast symlinks and store a pointer in the file system. The size reported for a symlink is the size of the pointer.  This simplicity of symlinks is the main advantage over aliases which are stored as files.

Comment: A symlink is a file *object type* so the adage “everything  is a file in Unix” can and still applies.  If you get the [*inode number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) of the file (`ls -i foo.bar` where `foo.bar` is a symlink) you will see that it’s a valid object and can be treated as such.  I think you may be conflating the partitioning scheme (FAT, APFS, NTFS, etc.) and how it maps to files via pointers versus the [OS file system](https://rb.gy/uohgp) and how it handles the objects contained in it’s file system.

Comment: @Allan I find the adage a bit meaningless when you get to details. Spotlight indexes files, not inodes. An inode belonging to a file contains pointers to data blocks which are the file content which is indexed by Spotlight. The inode for a symlink contains a pointer to the linked file - it does not have any file data. Hence reasonable for the linked file to be indexed and not the symlink. Anyway this is just splitting hairs about the second sentence - it doesn't change the rest of the answer.

Comment: Spotlight indexes files *that it’s configured to index and find*.  If you use the [`find`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/v7/1/find/)command, it will find symlinks just fine.